# Set of strings efficient implementation

Tags: string, matlab, set

Is there an easy way to create a set of strings in Matlab?

I am going through a list of filepaths and want to get all names of folders at a specific level.
But since in some folders there are several files, I get these folders several times.

I know there would be the possibility to create a cell array and check every time if the current folder name is already in the array, and if not, add it.

Another option would be to use the java HashSet class.

But is there any easy inbuilt Matlab way to do something like that?
I can't use a Vector since it would create a vector of chars not strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately there's nothing as efficient as Java Set implementations.

But you can use set operations. Either `union` when you add, or just call `unique` on your collection with duplicates.

Comment: Thank you, I think I will just use Javas HashSet then.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [`rdir`](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/19550-recursive-directory-listing/content/rdir.m) script... MATLAB file exchange to the rescue!

Use it like this:

```
listing = rdir(name);
```

The function returns a structure `listing` similar to the built-in [`dir`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/dir.html) command.
It should save you the headache of iterating through a directory tree yourself.

Comment: Thank you, but actually the file structure is not local, it is in some versioning system, so I think this wouldnt work here ;) Also I already get a filtered list of files, which only contains the ones I need the folder of.

Answer (score 0):

How about "unique":

```
x = {'dog', 'cat', 'cat', 'fish', 'horse', 'bird', 'rat', 'rat'};    
x_set=unique(x)    
x_set =  
'bird'    'cat'    'dog'    'fish'    'horse'    'rat'
```

Comment: and then follow up with "ismember"